# How to handle dates that repeat indefinitely

Tags: php, mysql, calendar, date

I am implementing a fairly simple calendar on a website using PHP and MySQL.  I want to be able to handle dates that repeat indefinitely and am not sure of the best way to do it.

For a time limited repeating event it seems to make sense to just add each event within the timeframe into my db table and group them with some form of recursion id.

But when there is no limit to how often the event repeats, is it better to

a) put records in the db for a specific time frame (eg the next 2 years) and then periodically check and add new records as time goes by - The problem with this is that if someone is looking 3 years ahead, the event won't show up

b) not actually have records for each event but instead when i check in my php code for events within a specified time period, calculate wether a repeated event will occur within this time period - The problem with this is that it means there isn't a specific record for each event which i can see being a pain when i then want to associate other info (attendance etc) with that event.  It also seems like it might be a bit slow

Has anyone tried either of these methods? If so how did it work out?  Or is there some other ingenious crafty method i'm missing?

Comment: Ok so it seems like the consensus is to go with (b) and create an entry in the db only when I need to associate something with the event.  Points go to Maxem cos he was first but thanks very much everyone, is much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd take approach b and if someone adds something to it, I'd create a "real" event entry.

Edit:
How many periodic events do you expect and what kind of periodic events would that be? (eg: every monday, every two weeks etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Yeah, hadn't thought of combining the 2 - that sounds like it may be the best option so far.  I want to be quite flexible as to how often they can repeat - as well as every week, every monday, every month etc I want to include things like 'last friday of the month' etc if possible.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a single record for a repeated event. Then in case more info has to be added to a specific date, I would create a record for the attachment with a reference to the repeated event.

Comment: ok great, thanks.  So similar to Maxem's suggestion in that the single record events are only created when someone associates something with it.  I feel a plan forming... ;)  Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Third vote for option B - rationale being that the data should only ever be queried for a limited timeframe (i.e. start and end). For performance reasons I'd suggest that, in addition to storing the date/time of the first occurrence, number of occurrences and frequency that you also maintain the last occurrence in the database.

C.

Comment: Great, thanks for that! So sounds like the combo is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, generating recurring dates and checking if a specific date is in that pattern isn't all that bad performance-wise. There's only 365 days in a year. 10,000 days is already almost 30 years. which means, the size of the input/output is relatively small in a practical scenario.

This library may help (but it's javascript): http://github.com/mooman/recurring_dates